# a4j:poll calls the value methods of every ui:repeat on the page

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, java-ee-6

i have an a4j:poll in my pageTemplate that just rerenders a an Area that displays the number of unread messages a user has.

Problem is, that every value-Method of an ui:repeat on the page is called. It is not a rerender, just the method is called, but the ui:repeat is never rerendered.

The a4j:poll method in my template:

```
<h:form id="msg_notif_rep">
    <a4j:region>
        <a4j:poll interval="5000" render="msg_notif" limitRender="true" enabled="false"/>
    </a4j:region>
</h:form>
```

The reRendered Region is in a menuPage that is inserted into the Template:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="msg_notif">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="header_message_notification" rendered="#{generalServices.getNumberOfUnreadMessagesForCompany(login.currentCompany.id) > 0}">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="header_notification_image">
            <ui:insert name="notification_img"></ui:insert>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="header_notification_number">
            <h:outputText value="#{generalServices.getNumberOfUnreadMessagesForCompany(login.currentCompany.id)}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Now every value-Method ui:repeat in a JSF-Page that uses the template the a4j:poll is in will be called every 5 seconds, but the ui:repeat is never reRendered.

For example:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{!messagesCompany.showSingleConv}" styleClass="message_overview_cont" id="conv_overview">
    <ui:repeat value="#{messagesCompany.allConvos}" var="c">
        <tb:conversationOverviewCompany conv="#{c}" isTibConv="#{c.tibMessage}" 
                        containerID="#{rich:clientId('cont')}, #{rich:clientId('msg_notif')}, #{rich:clientId('msg_notif_rep')}" />
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Replacing the ui:repeat with an a4j:repeat doesn't change the behaviour, also removing everything in the ui:repeat didn't help. 
Various other methods (a4j:commandLink, getter-Methods for h:outputText ...) aren't called, only the value-Method of the ui:repeat.

Is there any way to stop this behavior?